# How to insert data on a table using a form?

Tags: html, django, django-forms, django-views

I want to POST a message to the *Message* table in my db, which contains the following fields:

- id;
- body;
- normaluser;

chat.html:

```
<form method="post" id="msg">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="comment">Message:</label>
        <textarea class="form-control" rows="5" id="comment"></textarea>
    </div>
    {% csrf_token %} {{ form.as_p }}
    <button type="submit">Enter</button>
</form>
```

views.py

```
@login_required
def msg(request):
if request.method == 'POST':
    form = UserCreationForm(request.POST)
    if form.is_valid():
        form.save()
        body = form.cleaned_data.get('body')
        raw_password = form.cleaned_data.get('password1')
        user = authenticate(username=username, password=raw_password)
        Message(request, user)
else:
    form = 'msg'
    args = {'form': form}
return render(request, 'accounts/chat.html', args)

class MessageListView(APIView):
def get(self, request): # lista objectos
    serializer = MessageSerializer(instance=Message.objects.all(), many=True)
    return Response(serializer.data)

def post(self, request): # cria objecto
    serializer = MessageSerializer(data=request.data, many=False)
    if serializer.is_valid():
        serializer.save()
        return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
    else:
        return Response(serializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

models.py

```
class Message(models.Model):
body = models.CharField(max_length=500)
normaluser = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

def __str__(self):
    return self.body
```

serializer.py

```
class MessageSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
normaluser = MessageUserSerializer(many=False, read_only=True)
class Meta:
    model = Message
    fields = ('id', 'body', 'normaluser')

class UserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
class Meta:
    model = User
    fields = ('id', 'username', 'email')
```

I am basing my view from the `def` I use to make a new user. But I'm not understanding how to change it to accept a message, which also receives the info of the user authenticated at the time he sends the message. I am using the django `User` table to create users and login.

Comment: Are you using a ModelForm? And can you show your models.ply, otherwise its difficult to work out what you need to do. Is the message part of the same model as  the user, or is it a related table?

Comment: @wobbily_col Thank you for the feedback, I have added that information!

Comment: OK, I am more confused now. 

You seem to have a mixture of views for processing JSON with Django Rest Framework and for processing  an HTML form with a standard Django view (you have posted views.py twice). And is the UserCreationForm form a ModelForm or not?

Comment: @wobbily_col I shall unite the 2 views.py, cause they are the same file! And I'm using both Django Rest Framework and standard Django views, because I need examples of both in my project. I UserCreationForm is a import: `from django.contrib.auth.forms import UserCreationForm`.

Comment: OK, you will probably need to inherit from the UserCreationForm and add a message field and override the save method to add the message field. I'll try and write up a proper answer in a few hours.

Comment: @wobbily_col Thank you very much for your time!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Django user creation form is for creating a user. You basically want to customise this to add an extra message field and save this as a related object. Your form should be something like this (not had a chance to test it):

```
class UserCreateWithMessageForm(UserCreationForm): 
    message = forms.TextField()

    def save(self, @args, **kwargs):
        user = super(UserCreateWithMessageForm, self).save()
        message_txt = self.cleaned_data['message']
        Message.objects.create(body=message_txt, normaluser=user)
        return user
```